# clone geojson feature geometry

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geodjango

Using Leaflet in a GeoDjango app, I have an underlying layer(town parcels), and another layer(open space parcels) which i'd like to update(add) by cloning the geometry only from the town parcels. I'd like this to happen on the admin page where other various fields are filled in. Althugh it doesn't necessarily have to happen on the admin page, just preferable.

This would make adding features less painful for users as opposed to tracing underlying features, especially complicated polygons.

I'm using the [django-leaflet](https://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plugin as well as the [django-geojson](https://django-geojson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plugin

How can I start thinking of the process needed?

I do not have the skills to write a plugin.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm looking for some ideas, not solutions. I'm sure this will evolve into numerous questions once I get started

Comment: Sure it can be done, you need to have a database serving GeoJSON using something like PHP, Then when they click on a parcel you capture the feature's geometry coordinates. Then post back the geometry to the Open space table in your database.  You would still have to later edit/merge the polygons but it would be an easy way to crowd source. May also have to be on your intranet or password secured.

Comment: Do you have the Python skills to create a custom admin page for the parks?

Comment: not really, but I'm going to give it a try